# v4 support library not detected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-support-library

I've been trying to use the sample code from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) but I can't seem to have the v4 support library to be included. I added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'` in the Gradle build script, I've also tried to add the jar directly but each time imports like `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` can't be resolved (I have to get rid of the `support.v4`

This leads to the `ViewPager` class not being found and `FragmentActivity` can't be resolved.

I've been having issues with the Android Studio update (any starter code being unresolved), so I've made a clean install before.

EDIT: Tried installing AndroidStudio on another PC, same result.

Comment: I've tried it, same thing.

Comment: Is your SDK up-to-date? If not, you might not have v21 of the support library available.

Comment: Yes, the SDK is up to date. I've actually added the support through  Project Structure > Dependancies > etc.

Comment: show us your build.gradle and like stkent ensure your sdk tools is up to date and ASide is using the folder for this you expect

Comment: Build.gradle:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}`
And, yes, up to date.